# Decode Linkedin region codes

Tags: linkedin-api

I've gathered json via Linkedin API. 
Node:

`[GetCompanyPageStatistics][followStatistics][regions]`

stores information about followers localizations, for example:

```
"regions": {
        "_total": 9,
        "values": [
          {
            "entryKey": "pl-8172",
            "entryValue": "18"
          },
          {
            "entryKey": "pl-8355",
            "entryValue": "2"
          },
          {
            "entryKey": "pl-8218",
            "entryValue": "1"
          },
          {
            "entryKey": "de-4944",
            "entryValue": "1"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Given values consit of country code and region code. Is there a way to decode the region? Linkedin API documentation isn't very helpful:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/reference/geography-codes

(there's only `eu.pl` for Poland without any information about region-specific codes)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a v2 api to get that data:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/standardized-data/locations/regions

E.g., hitting `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/regions/8172?oauth2_access_token=XXX` gets you:

```
{
    "country": "urn:li:country:pl",
    "name": {
        "locale": {
            "country": "US",
            "language": "en"
        },
        "value": "Warsaw, Masovian District, Poland"
    },
    "id": 8172,
    "$URN": "urn:li:region:8172",
    "states": []
}
```